# How do I copy a pose from one blend file and paste it to another?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, armature, bones

I have a pose in 1 file and I'd like to copy that pose to another file. I think this [blog post](http://linetestjournals.blogspot.com/2011/07/copying-poses-with-constraints-in.html) is in the right direction but I can't get it to work between 2 blender files.

I also tried running 2 Blenders and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the pose then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With your armature selected look in the properties panel at the object data tab.

The first thing you see at the top of the tab is your Pose Library pannel

Create a library and add your pose to it.
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Posing/Pose_Library

save your blend.

in your new blend, you can append the pose library (from the Actions folder). 
You can then add the poses via the Action Editor

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit old, but I stumbled on this problem and found an easier fix:

just copy the entire armature object to the blend file where you need the pose temporarily. Once you've copied it, go to pose mode and copy the pose. Switch to the other armature and paste it. Delete the source armature and voila, the pose has been transferred.